# Optimizing SQL Server query based on nature of input

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have **two inputs** and **two columns col1 and col2 in the tableTemp**

```
DECLARE @startTemp INT;
DECLARE @endTemp INT;
```

If the value of `@startTemp is 0`

```
select * 
from tableTemp 
where a IS NULL and b = @endTemp;
```

If the value of `@startTemp is > 0`

```
select * 
from tableTemp 
where a = @startTemp-1 and b = @endTemp;
```

Based on **@startTemp** is there any way I can write above query in single query
something like below?

```
select * 
from tableTemp 
where (if (a = 0) check a is NULL else check a = @startTemp-1)) and b = @endTemp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach with a single `WHERE` clause is the following statement:

```
DECLARE @startTemp INT
DECLARE @endTemp INT
--SET @startTemp = ...
--SET @endTemp = ...

SELECT * 
FROM tableTemp 
WHERE 
   (
      ((@startTemp = 0) AND (a IS NULL)) OR 
      ((@startTemp > 0) AND (a = @startTemp - 1))
   ) AND
   (b = @endTemp)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have better performance use a dynamic query like the one below:

```
DECLARE @startTemp INT;
DECLARE @endTemp INT;
    
DECLARE @sqlQuery nvarchar(1000) = 'SELECT * FROM tableTemp';
    
IF @startTemp = 0
    SET @sqlQuery = CONCAT(@sqlQuery, ' WHERE a = @startTemp-1 and b = @endTemp');
    
-- Add other conditions here 

PRINT (@sqlQuery); -- Just to see what is generated     
EXEC (@sqlQuery);
```